# Django pagination overhead with sorting

Tags: django, sorting, pagination

I try to implement pagination structure in Django with some sort options however, I can't figure out how can I do that properly.

**views.py**

```
def search(request):
    eList = Employer.objects.filter(eminence__lt=4).order_by('-eminence')

    paginator = Paginator(eList, 3) # Show 3 contacts per page

    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        employerList = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        employerList = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        employerList = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

return render_response(request, 'employer/search.html', {'employerList':employerList})
```

**search.html**

```
<div class="pagination">
    <span class="step-links">
        {% if employerList.has_previous %}
            <a href="?page={{ employerList.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
        {% endif %}

        <span class="current"> Page {{ employerList.number }} of {{ employerList.paginator.num_pages }}.</span>
        {% if employerList.has_next %}
            <a href="?page={{ employerList.next_page_number }}">next</a>
        {% endif %}
    </span>
</div>
```

This example works great however as you can see, for every navigation I need to get all `Employer` objects. After that `Paginator` handles the objects in query depending on page number. However, I think the pagination should be done during query and only get X objects that I want depending on page number. I can modify, of course, the code in that manner but I can't  figure out why people use `Paginator` although there is such overhead. I may overlook a detail...

My second question is how can I apply sort my list ? Should I modify my `url` and passing a sort method and page number, and depending on them get the quesy by sort method and give it to `Paginator` ?

This seems reasonable and fine by me but I just wonder is there any better approach to do in django.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Django is very smart about lazy-loading the data, which makes these queries very efficient.  Let's walk through what happens with your requests...

```
eList = Employer.objects.filter(eminence__lt=4).order_by('-eminence')
## No database query.

paginator = Paginator(eList, 3)
## No database query.

employerList = paginator.page(2)
## SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `yourproject_employer`
## WHERE `yourproject_employer`.`eminence` < 4

 # Force iteration.  Same as looping over results:
foo = list(employerList.object_list)
## SELECT * FROM `yourproject_employer`
## WHERE `yourproject_employer`.`eminence` < 4
## ORDER BY `yourproject_employer`.`eminence` DESC
## LIMIT 3 OFFSET 3
```

As for your sorting question, I would say to simply modify the `GET` arguments as you suggested.  Just be **very** careful passing this to the database.  I would, for example, make a list of possible sorts and verify against that.  This also means you don't have to expose the inner-workings of your database.

```
VALID_SORTS = {
    "pk": "pk",
    "pkd": "-pk",
    "em": "eminence",
    "emd": "-eminence",
}
DEFAULT_SORT = 'pk'
def search(request):
    sort_key = request.GET.get('sort', DEFAULT_SORT) # Replace pk with your default.
    sort = VALID_SORTS.get(sort_key, DEFAULT_SORT)

    eList = Employer.objects.filter(eminence__lt=4).order_by(sort)
```

Comment: I knew it the django developers are smarter tahn me :) Thanks for security suggestion by the way I was applying "if else" control but it seems more elegant solution

Comment: I actually just implemented 90% of this on my site yesterday, so I am glad to help.  `=-]`

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly suggest endless_pagination. It is an awsum app.
Check out the sample project in here : https://github.com/venkasub/endless_pagination_example

Answer (score 0):

Actually Paginator depends on slicing of QuerySet.  Slicing is dependent on particular database - if django db adaptor supports it (e.g. transfers slice limits to SQL query - to something like LIMIT x OFFSET y for mysql or something else for other db). If this is supported, then query fetches only rows for given page.
I believe that for MySQL this feature is disabled now (I was looking into Django 1.3), because of performance issue with OFFSET clause.